# Barplot of percentages

Tags: r

sample data:

```
a <- data.frame()
a <- cbind(sample(1:4, 100,replace = T))
a <- cbind(a,sample(0:1, 100,replace = T))
colnames(a) <- c("Group","Event")
```

I would like to display a barplot where the X axis is the groups, and the Y axis is the of the percentage of events in each group, with the N of the group somewhere in the plot itself.
I would also like it to be ordered by height.

I can't seem to solve this one, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Inserting another column displaying for the event rate, but I can't get it to plot correctly which I understand why.

Comment: I thought about adding another column with the N of each group, but not sure this will get me where I need.
Also tried plotting y as mean(eventRate). No luck either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started

```
a %>% 
    dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Group) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(PCT=sum(Event)/dplyr::n(),
                     N=dplyr::n(),
                     LABEL=paste("N=",N)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=Group,y=PCT,label=LABEL)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_col() +
    ggplot2::geom_label()
```

[image]

```
a %>% 
    dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Event=as.factor(Event)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=Group,fill=Event)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_bar(position="fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! thank you.
Any thoughts about how to order the display so that the bars go from low to high on the X axis?

Comment: in the first plot you could do something like "x=reorder(Group,PCT)"